# C++, removing and couting all vowel in a string

Tags: c++

The purpose of my program is to get a string from user input, remove and count all the vowel. Also, the program would keep running until they hit a "---" to end the program. However, I am stuck and cannot figure what's wrong with my program. Eg: if the user input: "How are you?", output should be: "Hw r y?".
Sorry for being a noob, it is my first programming language and I'm quite inexperience with it.

=====================================================

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a sentence" << endl;

    string sentence;

    getline(cin,sentence);

    while (true) {
        getline(cin, sentence);

        if (sentence = "---")
            break;

        int j, a, e, i, o, u;
        for (j = 0; j < sentence.length(); j++)
        {
            if (sentence[j] == "a" || sentence == "A")
            {
                a++;
            }
            else if (sentence[j] == "e" || sentence == "E")
            {
                e++;
            }
            else if (sentence[j] == "i" || sentence == "I")
            {
                i++;
            }
            else if (sentence[j] == "o" || sentence == "O")
            {
                o++;
            }
            else if (sentence[j] == "u" || sentence == "U")
            {
                u++;
            }
            cout << sentence << "number of " << "a :" << a << "e :" << e << "i :" << i << "o :" << o << "u :" << u;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should be `if (sentence[j] == 'a' || sentence[j] == 'A')`

Comment: I'd recommend to turn on all compiler warnings. If you're asking about debugging help here add any compiler error messages verbatim to your question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (sentence = "---")
   break;
```

That is an assignment. It'll always happen, and it'll always be truthy. Thus your loop does nothing.

The equality-comparison operator is `==`, not `=`.

Also, you wrote `sentence[j] == "e"` instead of `sentence[j] == 'e'`, and you wrote `sentence == "A"` instead of `sentence[j] == 'A'`.